# What is the difference between Boxing and AutoBoxing in Java?

Tags: java, boxing

What is the difference between Boxing and AutoBoxing in Java? Several Java Certification books use two such terms. Do they refer to the same thing that is Boxing?

Comment: @Tunaki Well, not necessarily. This could be considered boxing: `Integer i = new Integer(1);` and this autoboxing `Integer i = 1;`. However that's just irrelevant semantics.

Comment: Autoboxing is automatic boxing, right? You can box an `int` manually using `Integer.valueOf`, or you can assign your `int` value to an `Integer` variable and it will be autoboxed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Boxing is the mechanism (ie, from `int` to `Integer`); autoboxing is the feature of the compiler by which it generates boxing code for you.

For instance, if you write in code:

```
// list is a List<Integer>
list.add(3);
```

then the compiler automatically generates the boxing code for you; the "end result" in code will be:

```
list.add(Integer.valueOf(3));
```

---

A note about why `Integer.valueOf()` and not `new Integer()`: basically, because the JLS says so :) Quoting [section 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the
>   range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number **between -128 and 127
>   (inclusive)**, then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing
>   conversions of p. It is always the case that **r1 == r2**.

And you cannot enforce this requirement if you use a "mere" constructor. A factory method, such as `Integer.valueOf()`, can.

Answer (score 7):

In my understanding, "Boxing" means *"explicitly constructing a wrapper around a primitive value"*. For example:

```
int x = 5;
Integer y = new Integer(x); //or Integer.valueOf(x);
```

Meanwhile, "Autoboxing" means *"implicitly constructing a wrapper around a primitive value"*. For example:

```
Integer x = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Autoboxing** is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called **unboxing**.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 0):

- **Unboxing** is the conversion from the wrapper-class to the primitive datatype. Eg. when you pass an Integer when an int is expected.
- **Autoboxing** is the automatic conversion from a primitive datatype into to its corresponding wrapper-class. Eg. when you pass an int when an Integer object is expected.